# Share image and text whatsapp ios using flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, share, whatsapp

Currently i am able to share only text in whatsapp but i need share text, image and hyperlink through whatsapp using flutter for iOS.

```
NSString *content = call.arguments[@"content"];
 NSString * urlWhats = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@",content];  NSURL * whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlWhats stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
             if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
                 result(@"sharing");
             } else {
                 result(@"cannot open whatsapp");
             }
```

Comment: is not possible to share the image and text at the same time on whatsapp

Comment: is possible to send different message like one is text and another one is image???

Comment: ya its possible